# how to connect a korg volca beats to a computer (runing cubase)

Tags: recording, midi

Does anyone know how i would go about connecting a Korg Volca beats up to my computer so i could record drum loops into Cubase? I own a Scarlett 2i4 USB audio interface but i'm not too sure how to connect the Volca beats up to that either. I'm just not very familiar with what wires i need and where they go etc..

I have a midi cable and i tried plugging the midi in into the volca beats and the midi out into the interface but that didn't seem to work. Do i need a different sort of cable?

Answer (score 1):

Volca headphones out -> PC line in. Scarlett needs balanced signal, not sure what you need to connect to Volca.